# Passing props to screen not showing up fist time

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Hi i am new to react native and i have a problem,

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const CurriculumMenu = ({navigation, item}) => {
  const data = item.Title;
  console.log(data)
  return (
      <StyledCurriculumNavigator initialRouteName="Overview" navigation={navigation} item={item}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Overview"  initialParams={{data:data}} component={Overview} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Curriculum" initialParams={{data:data}} component={Curriculum} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Teachers" initialParams={{data:data}} component={Teachers} />
      </StyledCurriculumNavigator>

  );
}
```

so this is a nested navigator and i am trying to send params to the screens in this navigator

```
export const Teachers = ({data}) => {
    console.log(data)
            return(
                <View>
                    < TeacherModule />
                    < TeacherModule />
                    < TeacherModule />
                </View>

        )
};
```

(i know i need to use flatlist, i am doing that when i fixed this problem)

so in my main navigator the console.log(data) gives me back the data but in the Teachers module it gives me'undefined'

what am i doing wrong? sorry i am such a noob

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `route` prop.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#initial-params

```
export const Teachers = ({route}) => {
    const data = route.params.data
    console.log(data)
            return(
                <View>
                    < TeacherModule />
                    < TeacherModule />
                    < TeacherModule />
                </View>

        )
};
```